# How to divide 2 aggregated columns using groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

In the titanic dataset, I wish to calculate the percentage of passengers who survived with each of Passenger class (Pclass) 1,2 & 3. I figured out how to get the count of passengers and no. of passengers who survived using group by as below:

```
train[['PassengerId','Pclass','Survived']]\
    .groupby('Pclass')\
    .agg(PassengerCount=pd.NamedAgg(column='PassengerId', aggfunc='count'), 
         SurvivedPassengerCount=pd.NamedAgg(column='Survived',aggfunc='sum'))
```

So, I get the below output:

```
        PassengerCount  SurvivedPassengerCount
Pclass                                        
1                  216                     136
2                  184                      87
3                  491                     119
```

But how do I get a percentage column? I want the output as below:

```
        PassengerCount  SurvivedPassengerCount  PercSurvived
Pclass                                                             
1                  216                     136                     62.9%
2                  184                      87                     47.3%
3                  491                     119                     24.2%
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sum the passengers as totpassengers  then create a new column df['perc'] = df.passengerconnt/totpassengers

Comment: @Tarik - Hi.. I want to accomplish this in one step. Also I didn't want to save this output in a dataframe.. is there a way to do this?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301973/pandas-make-pivot-table-with-percentage although I do not see the point of avoiding an extra statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to divide `SurvivedPassengerCount` by `PassengerCount`, you can do this using the `.assign` method:

```
result = train[['PassengerId','Pclass','Survived']]\
            .groupby('Pclass')\
            .agg(PassengerCount=pd.NamedAgg(column='PassengerId', aggfunc='count'), 
                 SurvivedPassengerCount=pd.NamedAgg(column='Survived',aggfunc='sum'))\
    
result = result.assign(PercSurvived=df['PassengerCount']/df['SurvivedPassengerCount'])
```